# Get typeface of Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, typeface

i want to get a String value for current typeface of EditText in android.
i am using edittext.setTypeFace(); and return a typeface,i was wondering how could i get a string value 
for it,Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: means you want to find name of typeface or get value of edittext?

Comment: i think you get TypeFace value using getTypeFace() and compare with TypeFace Constant like BOLD,ITALIC,BOLD_ITALIC,NORMAL.